# Firebase dynamic link is not working in IOS But works fine in Android

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

The Firebase dynamic link I created is working fine in Android. But, on IOS it shows invalid link when it pressed.I have been stuck on this issue for two days and could not find any solution for that.

This is my code:

```
Future<Uri> getLinK() async {
  final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: "https://develop3.example.in",
      link: Uri.parse("http://develop3.example.in.page.link/DummyPage/' + id + '/' + type"),
    androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(packageName: "com.example.app"),
      iosParameters: const IOSParameters(bundleId: "com.example.app")
  );

  final dynamicLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);
  return dynamicLink;
}
```

**This is error I am getting:** `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

When i open the link it shows invalid domain link

[image: IOS Screenshot]

Flutter version: 2.10.5
IOS mobile version: 15

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/receive#apple-platforms have you performed these steps ?

Comment: yes It was working fine in android

Comment: Do you have sure that the Bundle ID is correct?

Comment: yes the bundle ID is correct. I have added the error message i am getting please check.

Answer (score 0):

Please add app_store_id in parameters

iosParameters: IOSParameters(
bundleId: 'your_app_bundle_id(same as to package name)',
minimumVersion: '1',
appStoreId: 'App_Store_ID(can get from firebase project setting option)'),